# What pointer type to return to NASM from a ctypes callback?

Tags: pointers, nasm, ctypes

I am calling a NASM 64 dll from ctypes; it includes a callback to the SciPy function integrate.dblquad.  The callback receives a pointer to an array of two doubles and returns a pointer to an array of two doubles.  The callback function executes correctly and shows the correct results in Python, but I am having trouble returning the pointer back to NASM.

I posted this question on May 12 as a ctypes question at [What is the correct pointer type to return from a ctypes callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307916/what-is-the-correct-pointer-type-to-return-from-a-ctypes-callback).  I received an answer based on C language with a solution I can't use in NASM.  I hope someone can help with how this could work in NASM rather than C.

Here is the part of the ctypes code that calls the dll and executes the callback:

```
CA_data1 = (ctypes.c_double * len(data1))(*data1)
CA_data2 = (ctypes.c_double * len(data2))(*data2)
hDLL = ctypes.WinDLL("C:/NASM_Test_Projects/SciPy_Test/SciPy_Test.dll")
CallName = hDLL.Main_Entry_fn
CallName.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong)]
CallName.restype = ctypes.c_double

ret_ptr = CallName(CA_data1,CA_data2,length_array_out,lib_call)
```

Here is the callback code:

```
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
import ctypes

    def LibraryCall(ptr):
      n = ctypes.cast(ptr,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
      x = n[0]
      y = n[1]
      area = dblquad(lambda x, y: x*y, 0, 0.5, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1-2*x)
      return_val = area[0], area[1]
      r_val = (ctypes.c_double * len(return_val))(*return_val)
      rv = ctypes.cast(r_val,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
          #All three of these return the same data:
      return (r_val)
      #return (rv)
      #return (return_val)

lib_call = LibraryCB(LibraryCall)
lib_call = ctypes.cast(lib_call,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong))
```

I have also tried using these declarations, but there is no difference:

```
LibraryCB = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

LibraryCB = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

Here is the part of the NASM code that calls the callback and receives the pointer back from the callback in the variable [dblquad_Pointer]):

```
pop rbp
pop rdi
sub rsp,32
call [scipy.integrate_dblquad_Pointer]
add rsp,32
push rdi
push rbp
mov [dblquad_Pointer],rax

; check the values returned
lea rdi,[rel dblquad_Pointer]
mov rbp,qword [rdi] ; Return Pointer
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp]
ret
```

I have tried three separate calls to return the pointer to the dll:

```
    return (r_val)
    return (rv)
    return (return_val)
```

All three of them return the same incorrect result from the dll back to ctypes.

The proposed solution when I posted this last was to change the DLL code to use an input/output parameter, with an example in C, but I know of no equivalent in NASM.

So to sum it up, my question is, if I have a callback from a NASM dll sending and receiving pointers, how do I handle the pointer returned back to the dll?

Comment: "I received an answer based on C language with a solution I can't use in NASM".  Why can't you?  C compiles to assembly.  Allocate space for two doubles on the stack, pass the address of them to the callback as a parameter.  The callback fills them out...just like the C code in the other answer.  You're already passing the pointer to two doubles...just use *that* memory to return the new values.  The problem with your current callback is that it is allocating the memory for the return value in a local variable, and that is released when the function returns to C.

Comment: Your solution to use the memory passed in seems like it would work for an array of any length.  First I need to work out the details of using the pointer passed in to pass the results back.  I will try ptr = (ctypes.c_double * len(return_val))(*return_val) and return (ptr) (the pointer that was passed in).

Comment: You don't have to return anything.  Just write to the pointer passed in.  See the Python code in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354502/235698).

Answer (score 0):

Mark Tolonen's answer above works if I do it like I show here.

In ctypes:

```
def LibraryCall(ptr):
    x = ptr[0]
    y = ptr[1]
    area = dblquad(lambda x, y: x*y, 0, 0.5, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1-2*x)
    ptr[0] = area[0] #new
    ptr[1] = area[1] #new
    return (ptr)
```

The most important part is that on return to the dll I had done this to check the return values:

```
mov [dblquad_Pointer],rax
lea rdi,[rel dblquad_Pointer]
mov rbp,qword [rdi] ; Return Pointer
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp]
```

That's wrong.  On entry to the callback, I had put the values into a local array callback_data_vals and passed that to the callback:

```
mov rdi,callback_data_vals
movsd [rdi],xmm0
movsd [rdi+8],xmm1
mov rcx,callback_data_vals
[make the call to the callback]
```

On return, the returned values are in the same place (callback_data_vals).  Access them like this:

```
mov rdi,callback_data_vals
movsd xmm0,[rdi]
movsd xmm1,[rdi+8]
```

For a much longer array that won't be practical because the new values would have to be re-assigned in a loop in Python, which is slow.  Here with only two values it's trivial to assign them to the return pointer.